# Evaluating the ratio of minimum to maximum norm

Tags: optimization, euclidean-geometry, maxima-minima, nonlinear-optimization

Consider  a square grid in $Y-Z$ plane consisting of $(L+1)^2$ points ($L$ is an even integer) centered around origin. The points in the square grid  are:

$\vec{s}_{mn}= (0,md,nd)^T ,$ where $ -L/2 \leq m,n \leq L/2$ ($m$ and $n$ are integers).

Now, consider a sphere with center $(0,0,0)$ and radius $R$ greater than $\frac{Ld}{2}$.

Consider a point $\vec{r} =(R \sin \theta 
\cos \phi, R\sin \theta 
\sin \phi, R \cos \theta )^T $. Here, $\theta$ is the elevation angle and $\phi$ is the azimuth angle.

For a given $ (\theta, \phi)$, I  compute the ratio: $f(R) := \frac{\min_{m,n} ||\vec{r} -\vec{s}_{mn}||}{\max_{m,n} ||\vec{r} -\vec{s}_{mn}||}$.

My aim is to derive an analytical expression for $r_{m}(\theta, \phi)$ given by:
$$
\begin{aligned}
r_{\mathrm{m}}(\theta,\phi)= & \arg \min _R R \\
& \text { s.t. } \frac{\min_{m,n} ||\vec{r} -\vec{s}_{mn}||}{\max_{m,n} ||\vec{r} -\vec{s}_{mn}||} \geq \Gamma,
\end{aligned},
$$
where $\gamma$ is a threshold (say 0.9 for example).

Can someone help me establish the analytical expression for $r_m$?

My simulations show the following:

1. $r_m$ is minimum when $\theta =\pi/2$, $\phi =0$. Intuitively, this makes sense as the point is in the x-axis, so it would be perpendicular/normal to the square grid in the YZ plane.
2. $r_m$ is maximum when  $\phi =\pi/2$. (Not sure for what values of $\theta$ though?, simulations says maybe for multiple $\theta$ values this can happen) Intuitively, this also makes sense as the point is in the YZ-plane and would be parallel to the square grid in the YZ plane.